# jquery UI autocomplete remote multiple value option

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I currently have a code working using the UI autocomplete and seems to display the correct data I get from my mysql DB. Now I want to complicate things by been able to accept more than 1 value. I have searched the internet up and down and still cannot fix my code in order to work, I am a newbie with jquery and specially with autocomplete. Here is what I have so far..

```
$('#companyautocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        //separator: ' ',
        $.ajax({
            url: "company_search.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                name_startsWith: request.term,                        
                term: $('#companyautocomplete').val(),

            },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        compid: item.compid,
                        label: item.value + ' (' + item.address + ', ' + item.city + ', ' + item.state + ', ' + item.zipcode + ')',
                        value: item.value,
                        address: item.address + ', ' + item.city + ', ' + item.state + ', ' + item.zipcode,
                        phone: item.phone,
                        problematic: item.problematic
                    }
                }))
            },  
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#companyautocomplete').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#companyid').val(ui.item.compid);
        $('#c_address').val(ui.item.address);
        $('#c_phone').val(ui.item.phone);
        if (ui.item.problematic!=1){
            $('#companyautocomplete').removeClass("ui-autocomplete-error");
            document.getElementById('Sendbutton').style.display="block";
        } else {
            $('#companyautocomplete').addClass("ui-autocomplete-error");
            document.getElementById('Sendbutton').style.display="none";
        }   
    }
});
```

This is the response I get from the company_search.php...

```
[{"compid":"36","value":"MCDONALD OF ALL SAINTS RD","address":"9261 all saints rd","phone":"","problematic":"0","zipcode":"20723","city":"Laurel","state":"MD","completeaddress":"9261 all saints rd, Laurel, MD, 20723"},{"compid":"37","value":"MCDONALD OF BOWIE","address":"4306 nw CRAIN HWY","phone":"","problematic":"0","zipcode":"20716","city":"Bowie","state":"MD","completeaddress":"4306 nw CRAIN HWY, Bowie, MD, 20716"}]
```

So far it all works as I want but it doesn't accept more than 1 value, how can I achieve this ? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you seen this demo? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Comment: Yes I saw that demo and tested it but was not able to implement the other responses like "compid: item.compid", "phone: item.phone", etc. I added: response($.map(response, function(item) {
      return {
       compid: item.compid,
       label: item.value + ' (' + item.address + ', ' + item.city + ', ' + item.state + ', ' + item.zipcode + ')',
       value: item.value,
       address: item.address + ', ' + item.city + ', ' + item.state + ', ' + item.zipcode,
       phone: item.phone,
       problematic: item.problematic
      }
     }))

Comment: This, according to firebug, returns all the info but the menu never shows up nor I can select the value I want.

Comment: can you display you html for this question

Answer (score 7):

Finally I found an answer to my problems !! 
This is the final code using multiple values/inputs with getting responses from a remote mysql DB.

```
$(function() {
    function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#companyautocomplete" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
    })
    .autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "company_search.php",{
            term: extractLast( request.term )},
            function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                  return {
                        compid: item.compid,
                        label: item.value + ' (' + item.address + ', ' + item.city + ', ' + item.state + ', ' + item.zipcode + ')',
                        value: item.value,
                        address: item.address + ', ' + item.city + ', ' + item.state + ', ' + item.zipcode,
                        phone: item.phone,
                        problematic: item.problematic
                  }
            }));
        }
    );
    },
    search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast(this.value);
        if (term.length < 3) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#companyautocomplete').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#companyid').val(ui.item.compid);
        $('#c_address').val(ui.item.address);
        $('#c_phone').val(ui.item.phone);
        if (ui.item.problematic!=1){
            $('#companyautocomplete').removeClass("ui-autocomplete-error");
            document.getElementById('Sendbutton').style.display="block";
        } else {
            $('#companyautocomplete').addClass("ui-autocomplete-error");
            document.getElementById('Sendbutton').style.display="none";
        }
    }
});
```

});

Now it works like a charm. I hope this helps someone else looking for an answer.

Comment: This was a big help to me in my project.  I was able to take your code, modify if for my needs and get it doing exactly what I wanted it to.  Thanks much!

Comment: insert value into two different input box